# Fetching data in Next.js with revalidateTag doesn't work - what am I missing?

Tags: next.js

i'm using next 13.4.3 and i'm trying to revalidate my fetch data with next fetch wrapper through revalidateTag. I can't find the proper way to make this work. In production mode (next build & next start) nothing get's re-rendered. Is this feature not working at all ? I spent the last day trying to make this work with graphql-request and since it doesn't work with basic fetch here i am.

I followed the docs : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/revalidating#on-demand-revalidation

I made an api endpoint where it call the revalidateTag method, and i made a special page to test this out.
Here is the code for the api :

```
import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const POST = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  revalidateTag('a');
  console.log('revalidated');
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
};
```

Here is the code of the page :

```
const page = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:1337/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
        query Settings($locale: I18NLocaleCode!) {
          setting(locale: $locale) {
            data {
              attributes {
                seo {
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        'locale': 'fr',
      },
    }),
    next: { tags: ['a'] }
  });
  const { data } = await res.json();
  return (
    <div>{data && data.setting.data.attributes.seo.title}</div>
  )
}

export default page;
```

Comment: Data revalidation feature is working as expected. You just need to refresh your page twice. The first time you refresh your page, Next returns previously cached content and revalidates your page in the background. You should see the updated data the second time you refresh your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that's my bad on this one, I didn't check if it was re re-rendering after a second refresh. As a comment said the feature works correctly, next start re-rendering the page on the first request that you get after revalidation so a second request will get new datas.

The above code works, and since I made this works on graphql (with graphql-request) here is the code of the query function that i call in my page.tsx :

```js
export const Client = new GraphQLClient(`${API_URL}/graphql` as string, {
  headers: {
    authorization: TOKEN ? `Bearer ${TOKEN}` : '',
  },
  fetch: fetch,
});

export const QuerySettings = async (locale: string) => {
  const queryVariables = {
    locale: locale,
  };

  //Add revalidate Tags to next.js fetch
  Client.requestConfig.fetch = (url, options) => fetch(url, { ...options, next: { tags: ['settings'] } });

  const { setting } = await Client.request<{
    setting: {
      data: Setting;
    };
  }>(
    gql`
      query Settings($locale: I18NLocaleCode!) {
        setting(locale: $locale) {
          data {
            attributes {
              seo {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    queryVariables
  );

  return setting.data.attributes;
};
```